# How can I change the gedit tab colouring?

Tags: debian, xfce, gedit

I'm using Debian Jessie, and xfce desktop environment.  I find the look of tabs for other applications, such as chrome, and the file manager (thunar), and terminal (xfce4-terminal), display the active tab as a brighter color than the other tabs.  The exception to this is gedit, which displays the active document as a darker tab, which is confusing when only two tabs are open.  I have tried cycling through different gtk/xfce themes available using the xfce4-appearance-settings app, but this affects the tab appearance of everything except gedit!  I'm using gedit 3.10.4 and xfce version 4.10.

I have tried to find the solution to this online, but I found myself going down various rabbit-holes of gnome and gtk and gtksourceview settings, which don't seem to have any useful documentation.

[image: gedit tabs]

Answer (score 0):

After having another search around, I discovered that I needed to use a theme that supports gtk3:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/364966/how-do-i-integrate-gnome-applications-properly-in-xfce

I ended up installing the 'radiance' theme from http://xfce-look.org/content/show.php/Ambiance+%26+Radiance+Colors+Suite?content=147891, which doesn't look very good, but at least gedit looks more modern now, and the current tab is not darker than the others:[image]